# Do all vectors must have a "Direction " and "Magnitude"?

Tags: linear-algebra

Pleases explain it as easy as possible,I started to learn linear algebra of vector a few week ago.If it so ,then the next question is that if I take an element(indeed a vector) of "any" vector space ,then how can I find its particular "magnitude" and "direction"?

Comment: show an example.

Comment: "Magnitude" is determined by a [metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_(mathematics)).  Usually (e.g. in physics) when we talk about vectors we use the [Euclidean norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)#Euclidean_norm) (i.e. the Pythagorean Theorem).  The "direction" is determined through a unit vector...that is a vector that is in the same direction as yours but with unit length (but that "unit length" is determined by the metric).

Comment: The answer to your question is no: the notions of length and angle are not defined for an arbitrary vector space. To work with those concepts you must equip the vector space with extra structure. For length you need a *norm*, and for angle you need an *inner product* (which induces a norm).

Comment: Consider a direct flight from city A to city B.  If we laid a map flat (e.g. the Mercator map) and mapped straight-line distance, this would be wrong.  Instead since we assume the Earth is a sphere, the shortest distance between the two means a path along a great circle of the globe (this causes the path to appear curved on a flat map).  This distance along this great circle is the magnitude of the vector connecting the two cities.  The _direction_ indicates the particular great circle that they lie on--that is, all cities on that great circle are "in the direction of A to B".

Comment: What are some easiest example of vector space where an element of that vector space does not have a "direction" but still it is a vector?

Answer (score 3):

In short, no.  When you are just starting to study linear algebra, all of the vector spaces you will see for a while are finite-dimensional vector spaces where the scalar field is the real numbers, and in these vector spaces, both magnitude and direction make sense.  Every vector in these vector spaces has a magnitude, and *almost* every vector has a direction.  But there is one exception:  the zero vector has zero magnitude but does not have any definable direction.

More generally (and you should start seeing some of these more general examples pretty soon in your studies), the answer to your question depends on what you mean by a "vector."  In order for a vector to have a magnitude, the vector space must support a norm, and not all vector spaces do; similarly, in order for a vector to have a direction, the vector space must support an inner product, and not all vector spaces do.  An inner product can be used to define a norm, though, so if a vector field suports having directions for its vectors, then it supports magnitudes, too.

Getting back to finite-dimensional vector spaces where the scalar field is the real numbers, these spaces support both a norm and an inner product, so magnitude and direction both make sense.  Except for the zero vector, as above.

Comment: Is it possible to find a vector space where all elements of these space support inner product except any one or two element(please give some other example)?If it yes then Is my concept correct that to become "something" a vector ,first it must have to become an element of a "vector space" which may support inner product or may not support inner product, that is not fact?

Comment: Don't get too far ahead of yourself too quickly here -- at this point, most of the vector spaces you will see are finite-dimensional real-scalar vector fields, and those all have the usual dot product for an inner product, which induces the Euclidean norm.  If a space has an inner product, that inner product is defined for all pairs of vectors.  The examples that don't have an inner product must, then, either have infinitely many dimensions (think a space where the "vectors" are actualy functions) or the scalars come from some field other than the reals.